# How to run C++ program in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

i have 3 files.

1. header(x.h)
2. functions with file handling using OOP(y.cpp)
3. main.cpp

In Fedora it ran perfectly with no warning or error

```
>>c++ x.h y.cpp main.cpp
```

or

```
>>g++ ++ x.h y.cpp main.cpp

>>./a.out*
```

I'm new to CodeBlocks, I installed *codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe*

Opened three files, then Build and run (F9) it didn't run, but gave 12 error, related to:

> undefined reference to 'pqr::abc' ...

please help

Is there any other alternative to easily run these type of cpp program in windows?

Answer (score 3):

Create a project, go to `Project->Add files...` an add `x.h`, `y.cpp` and `main.cpp` (add at least the .cpp files).

> undefined reference to 'pqr::abc' ...

is a linking error because Codeblocks can't guess that you want to link those files unless you add them into a project.

Comment: Thnaks for reply.
I did this before. well, by doing this, It opens a blank screen(and no error). But in actual program, it is printing some array elements.

Also, is there any other alternative to easily run these type of cpp program in windows?